# why jpackage icon not used in windows search toolbar?

Tags: java, javafx, packaging, wix3.5, jpackage

I am creating the installer using the following command. I am giving jpackage the icon to use

```
jpackage --runtime-image hellofx --module hellofx/hellofx.HelloFX --win-shortcut --win-menu --icon smile.ico
```

When i install the program the icon is used for desktop shortcut but in the search toolbar it still displays the default java icon. Is there a way to use the given icon in search toolbar as well? I appreciate any help. thanks!

[image]

**UPDATE:**

here it seems the icons are correctly applied to app icons in search toolbar.

https://walczak.it/blog/distributing-javafx-desktop-applications-without-requiring-jvm-using-jlink-and-jpackage

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Start menu icon is correct

[image]

Comment: Check C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and see which file the shortcut there for your app is pointing to. The shortcut on your desktop might be different to the one there. You can also try deleting the shortcut in start menu and reinstall, jpackage might be preserving the shortcut from a previous install.

Comment: @Campbell please see above UPDATE 2. The start icon is using the right icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally solved it. It was a caching issue like Campbell pointed out. For some reason the icon is cached. Here is an example.

I changed the icon to a camera icon. The new icons display in the desktop shortcut and in the start menu as shown below.

[image]

Before this icon i used a music icon. So in the search the old icon is still in place. So this icon is cached for some reason. Only if i change the app as well as icon then all icons are changed to the new icon. Maybe this is an issue with windows 10. So the issue is now solved.

[image]